# How to stop injection node repeating in node-red

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

So one of the basic nodes in node-red is the inject node which helps to start a flow. In "edit inject node" tab you can enable the repeat option and choose an interval between the consequent injections. My question is how can I stop this repetition when it has already started. It doesn't seem that there is any available option like this. More specific I would like to stop the repetition on two cases, either when a specific condition is met, or when a specific amount of time has passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post on Node-RED forum: [How to stop a inject node from working](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-to-stop-a-inject-node-from-working/39062)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you don't.

The slightly longer answer is:

You can place a switch node after the inject node that can be used to gate the output based on a condition, which can include the state of a context variable. How you change that context variable is up to you, but another inject node and a Change node is probably the simplest.